# Deleting Rows (Data Wrangling) in Python with csv and/or pandas modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a set of csv files I am trying to clean up before placing them in a database. These files are tab delineated, and come in two formats. One format looks like this:

```
Some text string

Field1\tField2\tField3\tField4
```

`Some text string` always starts with the same sequence, so I would like to use this to identify the files that need to be modified. From there I can drop the first two rows (the first row and the following empty row).

I have been able to successfully find files that start with this string, but I have only been able to do it by iterating through each row, which isn't the best approach for what I am trying to do.

Where csvFiles is a list of csv files in the directory:

In csv module:

```
for csvFile in csvFiles:
    with open(csvFile, newline='') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith("Some"):
                print("Found it")
```

In pandas:

```
for csvFile in csvFiles:
    standings = pandas.read_csv(csvFile, sep='/t', header=None, engine='python')
        for row in standings:
            if standings[row][0].startswith("Some"):
                print("Found it")
```

I would like to simply select the first row and check it with an if statement, preferably in pandas, but I have been unsuccessful. pandas interprets the first row as the header, and assigns row indexes for each subsequent row, so I can't select the first row by index. I have attempted to set `header=None` so that each row is indexed, but have still been unsuccessful in selecting the first row by index.

I am trying to figure out how iterate through the files in the csvFiles list, find the ones that start with `Some text string` and delete the first two rows, as well as some later rows, from those files only.

My ideal solution would start something like this:

```
for csvFile in csvFiles:
    standings = pandas.read_csv(csvFile, sep='/t', header=None, engine='python')
        if standings[row][0].startswith("Some"):
            print("Found it")
            #do some stuff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are simply matching a line of text, there is no benefit to using Pandas for this (in fact it will probably be slower and more difficult).  But you can open each file just once if you're careful:

```
for csvFile in csvFiles:
    with open(csvFile) as f:
        line = f.readline()
        if line.startswith("Some"):
            f.readline() # skip one more line (validate it if you like)
            df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', header=None)
            # now  you have the data you want
```

The idea is to just pass the open file handle to `read_csv()` and let it continue reading after you have consumed the "metadata" which it doesn't need.

You may also want to specify the column names and/or types to `read_csv()`, so that your DataFrames come out looking the way you want without further manipulation.  Specifying the dtypes ahead of time can speed up parsing of large files.